# JS play sound on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm using a select input (one element will be all the times "selected"). Now when the user hits the demoPlay button the currently selected sound should be played, see my code for this.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="notificationSounds" name="notificationSound">
  <option value="1">Beep sound</option>
  <audio id="demoSound1">
    <source src="/sounds/beep.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Playing audio elements is not supported by your browser
  </audio>

  <option value="2" selected>Funny sound</option>
  <audio id="demoSound2">
    <source src="/sounds/frog.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    Playing audio elements is not supported by your browser
  </audio>
</select>

<button type="button" id="demoPlay" class="btn btn-success">Play sound</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demoPlay").click(function() {
      selected_element = "notificationDemo_" + $('#notificationSounds').find(":selected").val();
      $("#selected_element").play()
    })
  })
</script>
```

For some reason it returns:

> Returns: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).play is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues here. Firstly, you cannot place `audio` elements *within* a `select`, only `option` elements. Move them outside.

Secondly, you're using the string literal `'#selected_element'` as a jQuery selector, whereas `selected_element` is a variable whose *value* you need to concatenate to the selector, ie. `$('#' + selected_element)`.

You're also looking for the `#notificationDemo_N` element, when the `audio` actually have the `id` of `demoSoundN`.

Finally, `play()` is not a jQuery method. You either need to `trigger()` the underlying event on the element, or call `play()` on the Element object directly.

With all that said, try this:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="notificationSounds" name="notificationSound">
  <option value="1">Beep sound</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Funny sound</option>
</select>

<audio id="demoSound1">
  <source src="/sounds/beep.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Playing audio elements is not supported by your browser
</audio>

<audio id="demoSound2">
  <source src="/sounds/frog.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Playing audio elements is not supported by your browser
</audio>

<button type="button" id="demoPlay" class="btn btn-success">Play sound</button>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#demoPlay").click(function() {
    var selected_element = "demoSound" + $('#notificationSounds').val();
    $('#' + selected_element).get(0).play();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`play()` isn't a jQuery function, so you need to get to the underlying DOM object to use it.

```
 $("#selected_element").get(0).play()
```